# Converting a View function into a CBV in django

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to change one of my view into a class based views for academic purposes,but i dunno where to start ,

This is my view

```
def friends(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    form1 = FriendsForm(request.POST)
    form2 = request.POST.get('delete1',False)
    if form1.is_valid():
        form1 = form1.save(commit=False)
        form1.creator = request.user
        form1.save()
        send_mail('Confirmation email',
          # this is a link you wanted to
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000%s Please accept the request" % reverse('user_confirm',kwargs={'key': form1.key}),
            request.user.email, [form1.friend.email])
    if form2:
        user1 = User.objects.filter(username = form2)
        form3 = Friendship.objects.filter(friend = user1,creator=request.user)
        form3.delete()
    return render(request, 'mtweet/friends.html', {'FriendsForm':form1,'DeleteFriendForm':form2})
else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('log-page'))
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Whay about https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: @victor i did see that and also searched the net.....but i dunno where to start converting.....a little confused

Comment: I havent done this ever, but if you try and then you post new questions about your problems you'll get more help, You have to try first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can work (Not tested yet):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView ##### Import the FormView a Class Based View
```

The class based View:

```
    class Friends(FormView):
          template_name = 'mtweet/friends.html'
          form_class = FriendsForm
          success_url = '/myurl/'

          def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
             self.req = request
             form2 = self.req.POST.get('delete1',False)
             if form2:
                   user1 = User.objects.filter(username = form2)
                   form3 = Friendship.objects.filter(friend = user1,creator=request.user)
                   form3.delete()
             return super(Friends, self).post(request, *args,**kwargs)



          def form_valid(self, form):
              form = form.save(commit=False)
              form1.creator = self.request.user
              form1.save()
              ## send_mail
              return super(Friends, self).form_valid(form)

          def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
              context = super(Friends, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
              context['DeleteFriendForm'] = self.form2
              return context
```

You have four ways to do the `request.user.is_authenticated`:

1:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required ##### import login required


class LoginRequiredMixin(object):

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls):
        return login_required(super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view())
```

2:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required ##### import login required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator ## Import method decorator


class LoginRequiredMixin(object):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
     def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return super(self.__class__, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the last two you'll have to pass `LoginRequiredMixin` to the `Friends Class`:

```
class Friends(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
      ###### CODE ##########
```

1. In the `get` method:

   you'll have to add the get method to `Friends Class`

   ```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('log-page'))
   ```

your url must be some thing like

```
url(r'^friends/$', Friends.as_view(), name='friends')
```

the 4 way is in the url:

```
url(r'^friends/$', login_required(Friends.as_view()), name='friends')
```

If you need some help ask, hope this help you.